# Use lapply to modify the data of an xts contained on a list

Tags: r, list, lapply, xts

I am trying to change the first data of all the xts I have contained within a list but I can't seem to figure out how the syntax would be for `lapply` to do this. I have tried with:

```
b = lapply(a, function(a) a[1,]=1)
```

But this erases all the other rows' data. Does anyone knows the right syntax to address to the first data and modify it.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your internal function returning the `a[1,]=1` as a result, therefore you didn't have the whole `xts` stored.

Use like this:

```
b <- lapply(a, function(a) { a[1,] = 1; a })
```

Another way is to use `[<-` (anonymous assignment):

```
b <- lapply(a, `[<-`, 1, TRUE, 1)
```

---

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(xts)

data(sample_matrix)
sample.xts <- as.xts(sample_matrix, descr='my new xts object')

a <- rep(list(sample.xts), 2000)

microbenchmark(assign = lapply(a, function(a) { a[1,] = 1; a }),
               anon_assign = lapply(a, `[<-`, 1, TRUE, 3))

Unit: milliseconds
        expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval
      assign 33.50660 39.90533 58.75338 43.74316 88.39256 128.15991   100
 anon_assign 29.95665 32.37879 44.80245 34.11000 38.87301  97.35795   100
```

---

Therefore, the anonymous assign version is much faster.

Comment: @NicolásVargas If the answer helpful, mark it as answered.